# Single thread event handler for a C# telnet application

Tags: c#, sockets, thread-safety, telnet

I need to read asynchronous data from a telnet connection. The Telnet library give an handler and so I set it this way:

```
public PortechGSMBox(string ipaddress, int port, String user, String password, int modulenum = 1)
{
            telnet = new TelnetWrapper();
            telnet.DataAvailable += new DataAvailableEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
            telnet.Disconnected += new DisconnectedEventHandler(DisconnectHandler);
            telnet.Connect(ipaddress, port);
            Login(user, password, modulenum);
}

private void DataReceivedHandler(object src, DataAvailableEventArgs args)
{
            output+=args.data
}
```

I saw that the received data is not received in the correct order, maybe because the event comes from many thread. So if the server sends "123456789" I can receive "56781234".
I tried to add [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] before the DataHandler, but doen't work.
What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen only when send numeric values ? , if so you must convert HostToNetwork order and NetworkToHostOrder , these methods are exist on IPAddress class.

```
 // When Receive
 IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt32(bytearray, 0));
 // When Send
 IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(ID)
```

This will only help you if you are sending byte/ and receving byte, IF you sending an string  this way will not work.